# Take std of object array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array that is `30x30` and inside each element is an array of `400` values.

Is there an easy way to take the standard deviation of the entire 'cube' or to recast it as a 30x30x400 cube?

```
In [295]: data.shape
Out[295]: (30, 30)

In [296]: data[0,0].shape
Out[296]: (400,)
```

Doing `std(data)` gives an array of the shape `400` so it does not apply it to the whole thing. And taking the std of the result is not the same.

Here is an example of such an array and how to make it.

```
a = np.zeros([3,3]).astype(object)

for i in range(3):
for j in range(3):
a[i,j] = np.array([0,i,j])


In [364]: a
Out[364]: 
array([[array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 2])],
       [array([0, 1, 0]), array([0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 2])],
       [array([0, 2, 0]), array([0, 2, 1]), array([0, 2, 2])]], dtype=object)

In [365]: a.shape
Out[365]: (3, 3)

In [366]: a[0,0]
Out[366]: array([0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Are these NumPy arrays? If not, it seems like they should be. Then, taking the `std` would be simple using `np.std`.

Comment: They are, but its not a 30x30x400 array its a 30x30 array with an array inside.

Comment: I'd share a .npy file of the cube but I'm not sure where I could upload it.

Comment: @Coolcrab, can you share a 3x3 array with 4-element arrays inside? this would let people come up with a code that you could scale later if needed

Comment: I added the code to make one and an example array to this.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297460/convert-2d-numpy-array-of-arrays-to-3d-array

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about `std`, here is a straightforward solution for your specific case:

`np.std(np.array([i for i in a.flatten()]).flatten())`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got after a little trial and error.
Improvements are welcome

```
omega = x
for dims in range(len(x.shape)):
    omega = np.concatenate(omega)

y = np.reshape(omega,[3,3,4])
print(y)
```